# Read from partition in local cassandra node only

Tags: cassandra

I'm aware that I can read from any cassandra node and it acts as coordinator to read from the node containing a specific partition, but can I read data only from the partition which is on the node I'm connecting to?

In other words, when a cassandra cluster has 10 nodes, it contains 10 partitions on each node (and maybe replicas on other nodes when RF is set). When I send a SELECT * FROM TABLE I would like to get only 1/10th of the total data, which is really stored on that specific node without any traffic to other nodes.

Thank you so much!

Comment: what are you using for reading the data?

Comment: Java, datastax driver

Comment: It’s better to move this question to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as following (classes names, etc. are for driver 3.x, could be slightly different in 4.x):

- Identify what token ranges are handled by specific node - you can obtain this information from `Metadata` class as `cluster.getMetadata().getTokenRanges(keyspace, host)` (see [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getTokenRanges-java.lang.String-com.datastax.driver.core.Host-));
- for every token range repeat:

  - generate the query like `select * from table where token(part_keys) > rangeStart  AND token(part_keys) <= rangeEnd` (but this may not work all the time, as you need to handle cases when node's token range is split between end of token ring and begin of token ring - see linked code)
  - create an instance of `Statement` for each query (for example, as `SimpleStatement`), and [set consistency level](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html#setConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel-)  to `LOCAL_ONE` and host to which query should be sent (via [setHost function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html#setHost-com.datastax.driver.core.Host-))
  - perform query using the `execute` or `executeAsync` functions and process data

Source code that performs a full cluster scan could be found [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java) - you can reuse pieces of it regarding generation of queries on token ranges, etc.

Comment: excellent answer! I was not aware that I can use token() in where conditions. It doesn't matter, but the token function can't be unique and can have collisions?

Comment: yes, we have limited number of tokens - 2^64 in default setup - that's why we need clustering columns as well.